# How to use the existing Png-Shell-Thumbnail for my file types?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-shell

I am currently writing an application working with specially prepared image data. Another tool prepares the images (basically PNGs with additional data stored in the meta-data section). Now my tool works with these files, but not with all PNGs, so "we" decided to use a different file extension. So far, so good.

Now, because I am a lazy sack I implemented some file type registration to allow double-clicking on the file and opening it in my application (no problem at all).

And here is my Question:
It would be cool if the windows explorer could still show me the thumbnail previews for my files. Since they basically are still PNG files, it should be possible without writing my own shell extension (at least I believe so).

I quickly tried to copy all registry keys and values from HKCR.png to HKCR.mInDat (my file name ext) and it worked. However, I would prefere knowning what I am doing ;-)

Which of the registry settings are responsible for the thumbnail preview control and which can I use to get the preview for my file types?

I tried to google it, but I failed, since it seems I am unable to come up with the right buzz-words to find the info I need. Please, help me.

Thank you!

Yours,
3of4

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, I never found a good solution.I simply manually "cloned" the registry entry for HKCR\.png for my file extension. This works for the thumbnails, but obviously has problems for special shell commands. However, this project of mine got suspended for now, and so I am not activly looking for better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apng]
@="apng"
"Content Type"="image/png"
"PerceivedType"="image"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\apng\shellex\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{3F30C968-480A-4C6C-862D-EFC0897BB84B}"
```